# dimensionality reduction algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, pca, som, dimensionality-reduction

I have an  data sheet with almost 2000 input parameters and 4 output parameters.
I am to optimize the input parameters to define the output

I am not sure whether the input parameters are linearly related so I am looking for a non linear dimensionality reduction algorithm. Will Self organizing maps be a good option for reducing the 2000 input parameters to few  components.

I did try PCA but it is not quite helpful. Please if anyone could suggest any   standard algorithms and codes  that I could try?

Comment: What is your task? classification?

Comment: yes! i am trying to reduce the number of input parameters  so as to best describe the output..type of classification with optimzing the input parameters

Comment: See LDA dimenlionality reduction. Google it and you'll find useful info.

Comment: is LDA a non linear dimensionality reduction algorithm?                                                                  my input parameters are not linearly related...

Comment: See this link: http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/asr/project/sprach/report97/node164.html